# How to connect google DialogFlow (free or enterprise) to a SIP PBX?

Tags: google-voice, dialogflow-es

I am wondering if dialog flow can be connected to a SIP device, for a PBX system.

What needs to be done? What is missing?

Does dialog flow also include the voice recognition or is it only to analyze text and google voice does the recognition?

Answer (score 3):

Dialogflow offers integrations with phone services via Twilio for both their [Programmable Chat](https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations/twilio-programmable-chat) and [IP Messaging](https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations/twilio) systems.

If that does not satisfy your requirements you can create your own SIP PBX integration using Dialogflow's [query (v1)](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/query) or [detectIntent (v2) API](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent) to send user's querys from SIP PBX to your Dialogflow agent.  Dialogflow's v2 API includes [support for audio requests (both streaming audio and audio files)](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1#google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.QueryInput).